# Identity function with SELECT INTO - Need to change seed to dynamically get the last existing value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity

I have a table which has two columns as key (i_number + c_id), and I need to generate a new table from its values, but generating a new `i_number` so that the new table's first `i_number` for a certain `c_id` will be `max(i_number) + 1` for that `c_id` in the original table. Also, I will generate a new c_id for the second table, but this is not a problem. I post it as image as the data is provided in the fiddle at the end of the question. So, this is the original table:

[image: original table]

Given a certain c_id, let's say 001, I will be provided with a new c_id (let's say, 901), and the desired result its a new table with rows from the original table having c_id = 001, but generating a new i_number (in this case, it would be 3+1 = 4):

[image: required result]

I'm trying to accomplish this with a SELECT... INTO clause and using the Identity function, but it's not possible to use Identity providing a non-fixed value, neither a parameter...

```
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(INT, 
        (SELECT MAX(i_number) + 1 FROM table_fake WHERE c_id = '001'),
        1) AS i_number,
    '901' AS c_ooo, 
    m_value
INTO [table_fake_new]
FROM table_fake 
WHERE c_id = '001'
```

And I'd rather prefer not to use sp_executesql to do this. Any suggestion will be apreciated

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36c31e2aceead5204e9c2d29981a651f)

Comment: The parameter for *seed* on the `IDENTITY` function *must* be a literal; you cannot use an expression, subquery, or a variable. If you need to maintain an identity value over several tables, it seems like you should be using a `SEQUENCE` instead.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (Someone with 300+ reputation should know that images of text aren't well received.)

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the comments; I already discovered I could't use anything but a value for the identity seed, that's why I asked here in first place. Ok, I'll investigate about SEQUENCE. Regarding the "don't upload images", I already know and that's why I previously wrote that the example I was trying was attached in the fiddle. It isn't that obvious how to post a table with a legible format, and attaching the image was easier by far, and as the code was in the fiddle I found it appropiate. Sorry for the inconveniece though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve.  I just used window functions for MAX and ROW_NUMBER() to get the incrementing values:

```
SELECT MAX(i_number) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
            + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS i_number  
,'901' AS c_ooo, 
m_value
INTO table_fake_new
FROM table_fake WHERE c_id = '001'
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this help you.

ROW_NUMBER()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` and `IDENTITY` are not the same thing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).